# How to fix error calling pygetwindow's .activate: "pygetwindow.PyGetWindowException: Error code from Windows: 0 - Operation completed successfully."

Tags: python

I have an array of windows with a specific title.

When executing the `.activate()` command to an array from these windows, this error periodically occurs:

```
File "C:\Users\sakan\PycharmProjects\BIC\window_variable.py ", line 10, in <module>
    cmd_window[0].activate()
  File "C:\Users\sakan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pygetwindow_pygetwindow_win.py", line 246, in activate
    __raise With Last Error()
  File "C:\Users\sakan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pygetwindow_pygetwindow_win.py", line 99, in _raiseWithLastError
    raise PyGetWindowException('Error code from Windows: %s - %s' %(error Code, _formatMessage(ErrorCode)))
pygetwindow.PyGetWindowException: Error code from Windows: 0 - Operation completed successfully. 
It is worth noting that in the window that you are working with, you cannot move the cursor beyond the boundaries of the activated window.
```

The script is run with administrator rights and via cmd.

Comment: I don't know anything about pygetwindow... but an error code of 0 means that whatever command was executed was successful, which is the same as what the "error" message is saying "*Operation completed successfully."*. It is actually a non-zero error code that means an actual error. I suggest checking pygetwindow's docs.